# Who is better in performance filechannel or RandomAccessFile for reading and writing?

Tags: java, nio, randomaccessfile, filechannel

I recently came across [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), I am a big fan of [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). But I am wondering why would I pick `FileChannel` over `RandomAccessFile` for reading from a file and writing that content to another.

Is there any specific performance reason? I dont want to use locking of `FileChannel` for any purpose as I believe that could be one of the reasons why filechannel can be used. I don't want to use `BufferReader` or anything like that as suggested in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190989/randomaccessfile-vs-java-nio-file-channel-with-buffers) StackOverflow response.

Comment: Why? Well, *Currently I am using `transferTO` method of `FileChannel `to read and copy* is one good reason.

Comment: I mean I am not using it but eventually would like to but not sure how to identify if that is better than RAF

Answer (score 1):

FileChannel API says: A region of a file may be mapped directly into memory; for large files this is often much more efficient than invoking the usual read or write methods.

Comment: But they mention about the filechannel's read and write itself instead of any other read or write methods

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to choose between them unless you use a `FileChannel` with direct buffers and never access the data yourself, e.g. you only copy it to a `SocketChannel.` This is faster because data never has to cross the JNI/JVM boundary.

But I am wondering why you don't pick `BufferedReader`. It will *certainly* be orders of magnitude faster than either of these for reading a file line by line.

Answer (score -1):

RandomAccessFile is good in performance plus it allows to read and write most major types directly.

Answer (score -2):

**FileChannel**s are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

**RandomAccessFile source:**

*See that RandomAccessFile is actually using FileChannel under the hood...*

```
public final FileChannel getChannel() {
         synchronized (this) {
             if (channel == null) {
                 channel = FileChannelImpl.open(fd, true, rw, this);

                 /*
                  * FileDescriptor could be shared by FileInputStream or
                  * FileOutputStream.
                  * Ensure that FD is GC'ed only when all the streams/channels
                  * are done using it.
                  * Increment fd's use count. Invoking the channel's close()
                  * method will result in decrementing the use count set for
                  * the channel.
                  */
                 fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
             }
             return channel;
         }
     }
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/RandomAccessFile.java

Comment: This is incorrect. FileChannel is not used internally within RandomAccessFile and is only initialised is getChannel is called. Native methods are used to open/read/write the underlying file.

Comment: It is provided as a public method for anyone to get reference to the FileChannel for the underlying file.